# How to put an allocated array (sizes known at runtime) in a struct?

Tags: arrays, c, struct, malloc

To work on 3D arrays with unknown sizes at compile time, I wrote the following program that works :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  int x,y,z;
} dim3D_t;

void print_array(dim3D_t *dim3D, int (*my_array)[dim3D->y][dim3D->z]) {
  for (int i_x=0; i_x<dim3D->x; i_x++)
    for (int i_y=0; i_y<dim3D->y; i_y++)
      for (int i_z=0; i_z<dim3D->z; i_z++)
        printf("%d %d %d : %d\n",i_x,i_y,i_z,my_array[i_x][i_y][i_z]);
}

void alloc_and_init_array(dim3D_t *dim3D, int (**my_array)[dim3D->y][dim3D->z]) {

  *my_array = malloc( sizeof(int) * dim3D->x * dim3D->y * dim3D->z );
  for (int i_x=0; i_x<dim3D->x; i_x++)
    for (int i_y=0; i_y<dim3D->y; i_y++)
      for (int i_z=0; i_z<dim3D->z; i_z++)
        (*my_array)[i_x][i_y][i_z]=100*i_x+10*i_y+i_z;
}

int main() {
  dim3D_t dim3D;
  int (*my_array)[dim3D.y][dim3D.z];
  
  scanf("%d %d %d", &dim3D.x, &dim3D.y, &dim3D.z);  
  alloc_and_init_array(&dim3D, &my_array);
        
  print_array(&dim3D, my_array);
}
```

I found very convenient to access the array elements with syntax like `my_array[][][]` and only one memory chunk is allocated.

But, now, I would like to have the array as a member in the structure. How can I do that ?

I would like to avoid 1D array (i.e. to add `int *array` in the structure member and to access to elements using `my_struct.my_array[i_x*dim3D.y*dim3D.z+i_y*din3D.z+i_z]`) or to have many memory chunk (arrays of int **, int *).

#### Edit 1 (answer in fact)

Following the Lundin answer and the good idea of the "cast" trick, I wrote a program that do not use FAM. So, I could have more than one array in my structure. It is very convenient. There is only line to add at the beginning of the functions.

This is the code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  int x,y,z;
  int *array;
} dim3D_t;


void print_array(dim3D_t *dim3D) {

  int (*cast_dim3Darray)[dim3D->y][dim3D->z] = (int(*)[dim3D->y][dim3D->z]) dim3D->array; //cast
  
  for (int i_x=0; i_x<dim3D->x; i_x++)
    for (int i_y=0; i_y<dim3D->y; i_y++)
      for (int i_z=0; i_z<dim3D->z; i_z++)
        printf("%d %d %d : %d\n",i_x,i_y,i_z,cast_dim3Darray[i_x][i_y][i_z]);
}

void alloc_and_init_array(dim3D_t *dim3D) {

  dim3D->array = malloc( sizeof(int) * dim3D->x * dim3D->y * dim3D->z );
  
  int (*cast_dim3Darray)[dim3D->y][dim3D->z] = (int(*)[dim3D->y][dim3D->z]) dim3D->array; //cast
  
  for (int i_x=0; i_x<dim3D->x; i_x++)
    for (int i_y=0; i_y<dim3D->y; i_y++)
      for (int i_z=0; i_z<dim3D->z; i_z++)
        cast_dim3Darray[i_x][i_y][i_z]=100*i_x+10*i_y+i_z;
}

int main() {
  dim3D_t dim3D;
  
  scanf("%d %d %d", &dim3D.x, &dim3D.y, &dim3D.z);  
  alloc_and_init_array(&dim3D); 
        
  print_array(&dim3D);
  
}
```

Comment: There's really no way to do a runtime dynamic array of arrays in a structure like you want to. The best way (IMO) is to use a one-dimension [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) and arithmetic. You can't really get away from the arithmetic anyway, it's just hidden from sight in your example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flexible array members only work with one single dimension. However, it is safe to cast to/from them to array pointers since what matters for C's type system is that the variables are accessed through an lvalue of type `int`. It's a bit cumbersome to work with flexible array members here, since you need to cast. But quite possible.

Modified program with a bit of explanation in comments:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  size_t x,y,z;
  int array[];
} dim3D_t;

// the function gets a little bit more readable with a struct:
void alloc_and_init_array (dim3D_t** dim3D, size_t x, size_t y, size_t z) {

  // watch out for people using sizeof *dim3D style here:
  *dim3D = malloc( sizeof(dim3D_t) + sizeof(int[x][y][z]) );
  if(*dim3D==NULL) { /* TODO error handling */ }

  (*dim3D)->x = x;
  (*dim3D)->y = y;
  (*dim3D)->z = z;

  // cast from the flexible array to an array pointer type with same element type:
  int (*arrptr)[y][z] = (int(*)[y][z]) (*dim3D)->array;

  for(size_t i=0; i<x; i++)
    for(size_t j=0; j<y; j++)
      for(size_t k=0; k<z; k++)
        arrptr[i][j][k] = 100*i + 10*j + k;
}

void print_array (const dim3D_t* dim3D) { // remember const correctness
  // cast here as well:
  int (*arrptr)[dim3D->y][dim3D->z] = (int(*)[dim3D->y][dim3D->z]) dim3D->array;  

  // I cooked up a bit more "3D:ish" output:
  for (size_t i_x=0; i_x<dim3D->x; i_x++)
  {
    printf("[ ");
    for (size_t i_y=0; i_y<dim3D->y; i_y++)
    {
      printf("[ ");
      for (size_t i_z=0; i_z<dim3D->z; i_z++)
      {
        printf("%3.1d ", arrptr[i_x][i_y][i_z]);
      }
      printf("] ");
    }
    printf("]\n");
  }
}


int main() {
  size_t x,y,z;
  scanf("%zu %zu %zu", &x, &y, &z);  
  // sanity check x, y, z here....

  dim3D_t* dim3D;
  alloc_and_init_array(&dim3D, x, y, z);
  print_array(dim3D);

  free(dim3D); // remember to clean up
}
```

Input:

```
2 2 3
```

Output:

```
[ [   0   1   2 ] [  10  11  12 ] ]
[ [ 100 101 102 ] [ 110 111 112 ] ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the "cast" trick.

Comment: Lundin, will `sizeof(int[x][y][z])` work on systems that do not support VLAs?

Comment: @Stef1611 The thing with flexible array members are that they are allocated adjacently in memory, giving good cache coherence. Your program allocates the struct on the stack, then the array elsewhere on the heap. So that could potentially give ever so slightly worse performance. And you can't memcpy the whole struct etc.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica No. But seriously, who cares about portability to dysfunctional compilers from 1989 such as MSVC though? Those who use non-conforming compilers like that signed up for a flood of problems.

Comment: @Lundin. I agree with you about adjacent memory allocation and slightly worse performance. I do not use it when I need performance. Thanks a lot for comment and answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use a function to do the job for you.

Like that you can have only one allocation, and a easy way to access elements.

And that also allow you to handle out of bound errors.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    int     x;
    int     y;
    int     z;
}       point;

typedef struct
{
    point   dim;
    point * array;
}       t_array;

point * at(const t_array s, int x, int y, int z)
{
    // can check error here
    return (s.array + x + s.dim.x * y + z * s.dim.y * s.dim.x);
}

int main(void)
{
    t_array s;
    size_t  i;

    i = 0;
    s.dim.x = 3;
    s.dim.y = 3;
    s.dim.z = 3;
    s.array = malloc(sizeof(point) * s.dim.x * s.dim.y * s.dim.z);
    if (s.array == NULL)
        return (1);

    for (int i_x = 0 ; i_x < 3; i_x++)
        for (int i_y = 0; i_y < 3; i_y++)
            for (int i_z = 0; i_z < 3; i_z++)
                at(s, i_x, i_y, i_z)->x = i++;

    for (int i_x = 0 ; i_x < 3; i_x++)
        for (int i_y = 0; i_y < 3; i_y++)
            for (int i_z = 0; i_z < 3; i_z++)
                printf("%d %d %d : %d\n", i_x, i_y, i_z, at(s, i_x, i_y, i_z)->x);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I knew this solution. But it needs to write a function for each structure that is defined.

Answer (score 1):

Considering this `struct` and associated functions

```
typedef struct
{
    size_t x;
    size_t y;
    size_t z;
    int*** M;
} Matrix;

Matrix* so_create_m(size_t, size_t, size_t);
Matrix* so_destroy_m(Matrix*);
size_t  so_fill_m(Matrix*);
size_t  so_print_m(Matrix*, const char*);
```

And this program

```
int main(void)
{
    Matrix* my_mat = so_create_m(3, 4, 5);
    so_fill_m(my_mat);

    printf("\nMat[2][3][4] = %d\n\n", my_mat->M[2][3][4]);

    so_print_m(my_mat, "\n(test for 3,4,5)\n");
    so_destroy_m(my_mat);
    return 0;
}
```

that shows

```
Mat[2][3][4] = 234


(test for 3,4,5)
Matrix [3,4,5]

M[0]
000 001 002 003 004
010 011 012 013 014
020 021 022 023 024
030 031 032 033 034

M[1]
100 101 102 103 104
110 111 112 113 114
120 121 122 123 124
130 131 132 133 134

M[2]
200 201 202 203 204
210 211 212 213 214
220 221 222 223 224
230 231 232 233 234
```

A possible implementation follows...

Writing this way you can keep the usual array notation and keep the array inside `Matrix`.

#### code for the example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    size_t x;
    size_t y;
    size_t z;
    int*** M;
} Matrix;

Matrix* so_create_m(size_t, size_t, size_t);
Matrix* so_destroy_m(Matrix*);
size_t  so_fill_m(Matrix*);
size_t  so_print_m(Matrix*, const char*);

int main(void)
{
    Matrix* my_mat = so_create_m(3, 4, 5);
    so_fill_m(my_mat);

    printf("\nMat[2][3][4] = %d\n\n", my_mat->M[2][3][4]);

    so_print_m(my_mat, "\n(test for 3,4,5)\n");
    so_destroy_m(my_mat);
    return 0;
}

Matrix* so_create_m(size_t x, size_t y, size_t z)
{
    Matrix* mat = malloc(sizeof(Matrix));
    if (mat == NULL) return NULL;
    mat->x = x;
    mat->y = y;
    mat->z = z;
    mat->M = (int***)malloc(sizeof(int**) * x);
    if (mat->M == NULL)
    {
        free(mat);
        return NULL;
    }
    // now for the x[][]
    for (size_t ix = 0; ix < y; ix += 1)
    {
        mat->M[ix] = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*) * y);
        if (mat->M[ix] == NULL)
        {  // could not allocate all
            for (size_t i = 0; i < ix; i += 1)
            {
                free(mat->M[i]);
                free(mat);
                return NULL;
            }
        }
        // now for the x[][][]
        for (size_t iy = 0; iy < y; iy += 1)
        {
            mat->M[ix][iy] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * z);
            if (mat->M[ix][iy] == NULL)
            {  // could not allocate all
                for (size_t i = 0; i < iy; i += 1)
                {
                    free(mat->M[ix][i]);
                    for (size_t j = 0; j < ix; j += 1)
                        free(mat->M[j]);
                    free(mat->M);
                    free(mat);
                    return NULL;
                }
            }  // if()
        }      // for M[][]
    }          // for M[]
    return mat;
}

Matrix* so_destroy_m(Matrix* del)
{
    if (del == NULL) return NULL;
    // destroy M[x]
    for (size_t x = 0; x < del->x; x += 1)
    {
        // destroy M[x][y]
        for (size_t y = 0; y < del->y; y += 1)
            free(del->M[x][y]);
        free(del->M[x]);
    }
    // free(del->M);
    free(del);
    return NULL;
}

size_t so_fill_m(Matrix* mat)
{
    if (mat == NULL) return -1;
    for (size_t x = 0; x < mat->x; x += 1)
        for (size_t y = 0; y < mat->y; y += 1)
            for (size_t z = 0; z < mat->z; z += 1)
                mat->M[x][y][z] =
                    100 * (int)x + 10 * (int)y + (int)z;
    return 0;
}

size_t so_print_m(Matrix* mat, const char* msg)
{
    if (mat == NULL) return -1;
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    printf(
        "Matrix [%llu,%llu,%llu]\n", mat->x, mat->y,
        mat->z);
    for (size_t x = 0; x < mat->x; x += 1)
    {
        printf("\nM[%llu]\n", x);
        for (size_t y = 0; y < mat->y; y += 1)
        {
            for (size_t z = 0; z < mat->z; z += 1)
                printf("%03d ", mat->M[x][y][z]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I knew this solution. This is why I wrote in my question I would like to avoid `many memory chunks (arrays of int **, int *).`

Comment: Apart from all that extra "three star" complexity, these kind of pointer tables are also quite inefficient. The segments are getting scattered all over the heap, doing multiple malloc calls over and over is slow, as is the actual de-referencing too, since it is indirect and not based on offsets like when using true multi-dimensional arrays. The only scenario when you'd use something like this is typically when you need an array of pointers to strings with individual lengths.

Comment: @Lundin it all depends on the task at hand. If we really need to encapsulate the struct **and** keep the use of brackets, the `struct` itself maybe source of a very very long computation so the allocation time may be not relevant. I believe it is always pedantic to define things like _the only scenario_